# I would like to publish images, env public folder link & react app

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, web-deployment, github-pages

I have recently created my react portfolio website, and would like to publish it for free using github pages, or any other free domain. I don't know how to do so, as I have multiple things. I have my public folder will my projects images, and I also have my .env file with hidden information. How can I do this all?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried GitHub Pages?
All that you need to do is to create repo with your's github nickname and commit all your changes into this repo. Not sure about `.env` file and GitHub Pages, needs some research.

GitHub Pages - https://pages.github.com/